# How to resolve segmentation fault in Windows 10 bash shell?

Tags: windows-10, bash, shell

I am trying to run [ADMIXTURE 1.3](https://www.genetics.ucla.edu/software/admixture/) using Ubuntu on Bash on Windows 10 (Anniversary Update) using the following command:

```
./admixture --cv j2 bedfilename.bed 2
```

I am getting a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error.

I know that Microsoft say the Bash shell is in an experimental stage, but I was hoping that someone has already encountered and solved this problem. Is there any solution?

Comment: "In computing, a segmentation fault (often shortened to segfault) or access violation is a fault raised by hardware with memory protection, notifying an operating system (OS) about a memory access violation; on x86 computers this is a form of general protection fault."

Comment: What executable?

Comment: segmentation faults are very difficult to debug.  You have to determine what line the segmentation fault is happening at and fix the code.

Comment: Update your original post with the details of the commands you are trying to run along with the code/software version and any other relevant code.